# Si me llega más de un dato de una sola columna (Que es lo que ocupo).. ¿Qué tendría que implementar?, aunque sea en teoría

Tags: variables, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

```
DECLARE
    V_PRECIO CD.PRECIO%TYPE;
BEGIN
    SELECT PRECIO INTO V_PRECIO FROM CD;
    IF V_PRECIO>200 THEN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(V_PRECIO);
    END IF;
END;
```

Aquí podría poner un where con un id especifico así solo me traería un registro pero yo ocupo los registros de toda la columna, para ese caso, ¿Qué tendría que implementar?

```
Informe de error -
ORA-01422: la recuperación exacta devuelve un número mayor de filas que el solicitado
ORA-06512: en línea 4
01422. 00000 -  "exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows"
*Cause:    The number specified in exact fetch is less than the rows returned.
*Action:   Rewrite the query or change number of rows requested
```

En especifico ese es el error.

Comment: Pues en efecto te equivocas, je. Si la variable es un VARCHAR, recibe UN dato. Por qué supones que puede recibir un array? Para recibir un ARRAY de datos, toca usar otra cosa. Entonces, cada vez que hagas un SELECT INTO desde una tabla hacia una variable de un tipo de dato básico, te toca garantizar que le llegue exactamente UN dato.

Comment: Bueno gracias, ya cambie la pregunta

Answer (score 0):

Deberías usar un cursor y un bucle para recorrerlo. Algo así. (No lo he probado, igual hay algún error de sintaxis pero te dará la idea)

```sql
DECLARE
       CURSOR cemp IS
       SELECT PRECIO FROM CD;
       cepm_rec cemp%ROWTYPE;
     BEGIN
       FOR cemp_rec IN cemp
       LOOP
           IF cemp_rec.precio>200 THEN
             DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(cemp_rec.precio);
           END IF;
       END LOOP;
     END;
```